# downgrade to custom previous android os version [gt-i9190]

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I have just got a new galaxy s4 mini phone and it sounds a fake galaxy phone due to bad specfications :
internal storage :0.13 gb and ram is 453 mb only
os :4.4.2 kikat and kernel version :3.4.5(eng.whl.1406695459)
hardware:mt6572 and board mtk5689_wet_lca
I believe if I can flash it with older version of android it may work smoother is that right ? and if so how to do ?please help

Answer (score 0):

This definitely a fake phone. The problem is where do you want to get that OS? There is no support offered by those chinese firms which are faking phones.

My advice: Either get a proper, not faked phone or just stick to what you have. You may be able to uninstall some bloatware and you are good to go with that phone. It will not be as powerful as the original but it may help out.